# SQL - WITH RECURSIVE doesn't work, when there is another query before

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a (postgresql) query, that goes like

```
with 
recursive account_tree as (<recursive function depending on path>), -- 1
path as (<some other query>)                                        -- 2
select * from account_tree;
```

This works perfectly fine.

But when I reorder the with queries to that

```
with 
path as (<some other query>),                                      -- 2
recursive account_tree as (<recursive function depending on path>) -- 1
select * from account_tree;
```

it suddenly shows a syntax error. This behaviour doesn't occur, when I have standard non-recursive queries. With non-recursive queries, I can order them, as they please me.

Why does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recursive` refers to the entire `with` clause.  So just use:

```
with recursive path as (<some other query>),                                      -- 2
```

What `recursive` *really* means is that Postgres will search for "table" names first as CTEs and then as tables/views in the recursive part of the CTE.  The issue is really resolving identifiers.  It has no effect on other CTEs.

Comment: So, the recursive makes only queries recursive, which are designed to be recursive. It has no effect on standard queries, right?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz . . . It should have no effect on "standard" CTEs.

Answer (score 4):

The `recursive` keyword always goes right behind `WITH` regardless which of the CTE is actually the recursive one:

```
with recursive path as (
  <some other query>
), account_tree as (
  <recursive function depending on path>
)
select * 
from account_tree;
```